# How to secure NIFI site-to-site with basic auth

Tags: security, apache-nifi

My purpose is to collect some changed data of remote database to a nifi instance via site-to-site and internet.
How could I protect the input port on the internet via user/password ?
I'm not meaning ssl connection but prevent unauthorized invokation.

Is site-to-site suitable for this situation ? or use http processors instead of s2s ?

Comment: Do not expose your S2S port openly to the internet - use firewalls/NACL/security groups to lock it down to only your known NiFi nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I deploy a squid server as http proxy within the local network of central nifi server. With following configuration options, squid was restricted to invoke only nifi service and authenticatable:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/.htpasswd
acl nifi_host dst <nifi host ip address>
acl nifi_port port <nifi port>
acl auth_user proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow nifi_host nifi_port auth_user
http_access deny all
```

At the remote database side, config nifi site-to-site connection using http proxy with user and password.

By now, this solution works fine.

Answer (score -1):

A remote-access VPN can be used. It is a temporary connection between users and endpoints, usually for data center access. This connection may be connected to IPsec, but also an SSL VPN is frequently used to connect a user endpoint to a VPN gateway.

please check
https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/cyberpedia/what-is-a-site-to-site-vpn
for more info.

I hope this was helpful